# when trying to write your project with registration. I can’t find the link name I tried everythingю Django urls

Tags: python, html, django, web, backend

I have 2 chat and account applications but I don’t understand why urls are not found

account.urls

```
app_name = 'account'
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', Login_proverka, name='Login'),
    path('<int:user_id>/profile/', Profil, name='Profil'),
    path('exit/', Exit, name='Exit'),
    path('register/', Register, name='Register'),
    path('<int:user_id>/chat/', include('chat.urls'))
]
```

chat.urls

```
app_name = 'chat'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ListCHat, name='ListCHat'),
    path('<int:chat_id>', Chat, name='Chat'),
    path('<int:chat_id>/send_message', CreateMessage, name='CreateMessage')
]
```

chat.html

```
<form action="{% url 'chat:CreateMessage' %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" style="resize: none; margin: 3px; height: 114%;

}"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" style="margin-left: -39%;width: 127%;
margin-top: 8%;"><i class="fa fa-hand-peace-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" style="height: 57%;width: 123%;margin-left: -35%;">
                                <i class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                            </button>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

chat.views

```
def CreateMessage(request, chat_id, user_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message_text = request.POST['message_text']
        try:
            user_get = Account.objects.get(user_id=user_id)
            user_name = user_get.user_name
        except:
            return HttpResponseNotFound('Пользователь не найден, скорее всего вы пытаетесь зайти туда куда вам не льзя')
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if request.user.username == user_name:
                y = Chat_group.objects.get(chat_group_id=chat_id)
                user_chat = Chat_user.objects.filter(chat_user_id=user_id[0])
                name_user = user_chat.chat_user_name
                last_name_user = user_chat.chat_message_user_last_name
                x = Chat_message(chat_message_user_name=name_user, chat_message_user_last_name=last_name_user,
                             chat_message=message_text, chat_message_group=y)
                x.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/chat/{}'.format(chat_id))
```

I'm sorry that the names of the changes are so crooked. I’ll be blogging if you tell me where the newcomer made mistakes in django

Comment: Welcome to S/O. Please expand on your problem to include more details, possibly show some error trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your chat urls are a sub-namespace of your account urls. The names are

```
account:chat:CreateMessage
```

This is because in your account urls you have:

```
app_name = 'account'
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('<int:user_id>/chat/', include('chat.urls'))
]
```

If you install django-extensions, then run `manage.py show_urls` you can see all the urls available in your project.